# using MultiRNNCell in tensorflow 0.12

Tags: python, tensorflow

With Tensorflow 0.12, there have been changes to the way that `MultiRNNCell` works, for starters, `state_is_tuple` is now set to `True` by default, furthermore, there is this discussion on it:

> `state_is_tuple`: If `True`, accepted and returned states are `n`-tuples, where `n = len(cells)`. If `False`, the states are all concatenated along the column axis. This latter behavior will soon be deprecated.

I'm wondering how exactly I could use a multi layer RNN with GRU cells, here is my code so far:

```
def _run_rnn(self, inputs):
        # embedded inputs are passed in here
        self.initial_state = tf.zeros([self._batch_size, self._hidden_size], tf.float32)
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(self._hidden_size)
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=self._dropout_placeholder)
        cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([cell] * self._num_layers, state_is_tuple=False)

        outputs, last_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
            cell = cell,
            inputs = inputs,
            sequence_length = self.sequence_length,
            initial_state = self.initial_state
        ) 

        return outputs, last_state
```

My inputs look up word ids and return a corresponding embedding vectors. Now, running with the code above I'm greeted by the following error:

`ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 100 and 200 for 'rnn/while/Select_1' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [?], [64,100], [64,200]`

The places I've got a `?` in is within my placeholders:

```
def _add_placeholders(self):
        self.input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, self._max_steps])
        self.label_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, self._max_steps])
        self.sequence_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None])
        self._dropout_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main issue is in the setting of the `initial_state`. Since your state is now a tuple, (more specifically an `LSTMStateTuple`, you cannot directly assign it to `tf.zeros`. Instead use,

```
self.initial_state = cell.zero_state(self._batch_size, tf.float32)
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent/#stacking_multiple_lstms) for more.

---

To use this in code, you will need to pass this *tensor* in the `feed_dict`. Do something like this,

```
state = sess.run(model.initial_state)
for batch in batches:
    # Logic to add input placeholder in `feed_dict`
    feed_dict[model.initial_state] = state
    # Note I'm re-using `state` below
    (loss, state) = sess.run([model.loss, model.final_state], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: how could I continuously pass in the current state as a placeholder then given the above? The state currently is a tensor, so its simple for me to keep passing along a tensor that matches the dimensions of the zero vector.

Comment: You can pass tensors as well in the feed_dict. So if you want to pass a future state of the cell, simply compute that state using `sess` and pass it to the feed dict

Comment: I went with something similar to the above, I figured that if I just set the models initial_state to the cell.zero_state it would all work out fine.